# Kubernetes Dashboard deployed through Terraform and helm_release module is not working

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks, kubernetes-dashboard

I deployed kubernetes dashboard using Terraform into my Azure Kubernetes cluster, using the following code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">=3.0.0"
    }
  }
}


provider "azurerm" {
  features {}

}

provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    config_path = "~/.kube/config"
  }
}

resource "helm_release" "my-kubernetes-dashboard" {

  name = "kubernetes-dashboard"

  repository = "https://kubernetes.github.io/dashboard/"
  chart      = "kubernetes-dashboard"
  namespace  = "kube-dashboard"
 

  set {
    name  = "metricsScraper.enabled"
    value = "true"
  }
}
```

I am able to launch the Kubernetes dashboard in a browser with the following command:

```
kubectl port-forward -n kubernetes-dashboard service/kubernetes-dashboard 8080:443
```

[image]

However, when I try to use the `kubectl proxy` command, it gives me the following error:

[image]

I have tried multiple solutions but none of them have worked. Please help me resolve this error using `kubectl proxy` command? Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/visualizing-aks-kubernetes-dashboard-manoj-dhobale/

Comment: Thanks @Hackerman for the reference. I want to use helm_release module block for deploying kubernetes dashboard using terraform

Comment: Yeah, but did you check the steps that he uses to connect, like using the kubeconfig for connection?

Comment: @Hackerman the blog you suggested is also using kubectl portforward command in step-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using kubectl proxy, I discovered that the URL I was previously using was incorrect. After following the new URL it is worked as expected:

```
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:https/proxy/#/login
```